# JSON Date Formatting

Tags: jquery, json, date

I'm having an issue with the date format when getting JSON Date/Time.

I've managed to get the date format to:
2009-06-25T17:32:10.0000000

But I need to be:
25/06/2009 17:32:10

But since I'm getting this data from a loop I've trouble finding out how exactly to format the date so that the data is still extracted correctly in the loop. So far the closest I've come is using the Jquery FormatDateTime (which I've added a script Reference for at the start of the document):

```
//Get Pages Visited
        response.Result.PagesViewed.forEach(function (o, i, arr) {
            o.PageTime = $formatDateTime('dd/mm/yy hh:ii', o.PageTime);
            $('#PagesViewedRows').html("<tr class='info'><td>" + o.PageTime + "</td><td>" + o.PageStatus + "</td><td>" + o.PageName + "</td></tr>");
});
```

How can I format the o.PageTime to display correctly?

Comment: you want to store the formatted date for later use? or what?

Comment: Nah I want to display it inside <td>" + [formatted date here] + "</td>

Comment: First we need to know o.PageTime format...

Comment: "I've managed to get the date format to: 2009-06-25T17:32:10.0000000"

Comment: which plugin is this, exactly? jqueryui? or agschwender's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need JQuery for that.
Plain javascript works as well:

```
var date = new Date('2009-06-25T17:32:10.0000000');
console.log(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var d = new Date().toJSON().split(/-|T|\..*/).filter(Boolean);
var res = d.slice(0, 3).reverse().join("/").concat(" " + d.slice(-1));
console.log(res);
```